# GitLab archive over API creating endless zips inside zips

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

I am using the GitLab API to create repository archives and when I do it creates a zip file that has a zip inside, that has a zip inside, etc.

Here is the code that is making the request:

```
def self.get_archive(project_id, branch)
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
        BASE_URL + "/projects/#{project_id}/repository/archive?sha=#{branch}",
        method: :get,
        params: nil,
        headers: {
            "PRIVATE-TOKEN": ADMIN_TOKEN
        }
    )

    request.run

    response = request.response

    if response.success?
        file_name = "archive-#{SecureRandom.hex(5)}.zip"

        File.open(Rails.root + "public/archives/" + file_name, "wb") do |file|
            file.write(response.body)
        end

        return {
            success: true,
            file_path: "/archives/" + file_name
        }
    else
        return {
            success: false,
            response_raw: response
        }
    end
end
```

Any thoughts as to what's gone wrong? My thinking here was to take the binary that I get back and write it to a zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that GitLab sends back by default a tar.gz file. To receive the Zip file instead you have to explicitly specify the .zip extension to the end of the request. Like so:

```
"/projects/#{project_id}/repository/archive.zip?sha=#{branch}"
```

The .zip at the end of "archive" was the important factor.